# Is crossdomain.xml file a mandatory for flex applications to access server?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, cross-domain, flex4.5, flex4.6

In my flex application, the war is packaged with crossdomain.xml policy file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The entries mentioned here means the SWF file from any/all domain can access the server data.

My question here is

1. the crossdomain.xml necessarily need to be there for accessing the server ?
2. What happens if we don't have a crossdomain.xml policy file while the SWF file is accessing the server for data ?
3. Is there any default restrictions the server may have to access its data if we don't place a crossdomain.xml ?

Kindly, Please help me with your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the crossdomain.xml necessarily need to be there for accessing the
>   server ?

No.  It is required for a browser based SWF that is located on a different domain from the server.  But, a SWF served from the same domain does not need a crossdomain.xml place.  A Flash Platform App deployed outside of the browser, as an AIR app or mobile application will not need a crossdomain file to access the server.

> What happens if we don't have a crossdomain.xml policy file while the
>   SWF file is accessing the server for data ?

If the SWF is served off the same domain as the server; then nothing will happen.  If the SWF is on a different domain, then your remote class will dispatch a fault event; which will contain a security error of sorts.

> Is there any default restrictions the server may have to access its
>   data if we don't place a crossdomain.xml ?

Yes, but nothing I haven't already said.  A SWF served off the same domain as the server can access files/services on that domain.  A SWF served off a different domain cannot.

As an example a SWF located at `http://mydomain.com/mySWF.swf` will be able to access `http://mydomain.com/service/MyServiceEndPoint` or `http://mydomain.com/someImage.gif` without any issues.  It will not be able to access `http://myOtherDomain.com/service/MyServiceEndPoint` or `http://myOtherDomain.com/someImage.gif`.

Comment: hi Reboog711, Thanks a lot for your answers. This gives me a clear view about crossdomain policy file.

Comment: Great; if you think this completely answers your question be sure to mark it as the 'correct' answer.There should be a 'check' button under the voting numbers thatyou can press.